# classes and Loop inside python

Tags: python, class, object, for-loop

i am trying my first code in python writing classes and objects..

here is the code:

```
class Order:  
   def __init__(self,A):
       self.a= A

   def user1(self):
    x = len(self.a)
    i =0
    while i < x:
        value = A[i]
        y = value
        return y

A = ["AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF"]
honey= Order(A)
print (honey.user1())
```

i am getting output as AA................but i need to all elements from the A[] ,so only wrote for loop...but it print only output as AA.......

I need output as AA BB CC DD EE FF

how to achieve it using classes and object creation.....help pls

Comment: `return y` returns a value *from* the function so the iteration stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you doing is returning after it loops and gets the first value and thus it gives back only the first value

Also, you are not incrementing your loop this will result in an infinite loop.

something like this is what it should be:

```
y=[]
while i < x:
    value = A[i]
    y.append(value)
    i+=1
return y
```

Comment: thank it works fine now...........in python i+=1 is similar to i++ in c?

Comment: @dhiyash2008 : Not really. `i+=1` in Python is equivalent to `i = i + 1`. Whereas in C, increment in value by doing `i++` reflects in next usage of `i` and not current (which is not the case with Python here).